# How to fit an odd relationship with a function?

Tags: statistics, predictive-modeling, regression

Let's say there is a function $f$ such that $y = f(x)$. However, if $f$ is a piecewise function such that:

$$y = \begin{cases} 0 \quad x \leq 0 \\ 1 \quad x >0\end{cases} $$

How do I fit $f$ in that case?

Many thanks, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition you gave *is* the definition of the function. This is called the [Heaviside Step Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). There is not a simple *analytic* way to express it (like as a ratio, product, or composition  of trigonometric functions, exponentials, or polynomials). Note that it is neither continuous nor differentiable at x = 0.

There are a couple of cool ways to represent it. The coolest and most intuitive way is as an integral of a [Dirac Delta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function):

$$ 
H(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x { \delta(s)} \, \mathrm{d}s 
$$

Note, though, that a Dirac Delta Function is itself not an "official" function, since it is not well-defined at x = 0. Check out [Distribution Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) for some cool info on weird "functions" like this.

Now, I think you may be trying to approximate this function, because you asked how to "fit" it. Taken straight from Wikipedia:

```
For a smooth approximation to the step function, one can use the logistic   function
```

$$
H(x) \approx \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\tanh(kx) = \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-2kx}},
$$

```
where a larger k corresponds to a sharper transition at x = 0.
```

Comment: My description is not very clear, but you had already got my mind. Really appreciate !